# Oracle SQL - Number of cases between 2 failed events (G Chart)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below is sample of a data I am currently working on:

```
101     N   4/14/2016
201     Y   4/15/2016
301     Y   4/16/2016
401     Y   4/20/2016
501     N   4/21/2016
201     Y   4/30/2016
701     Y   5/03/2016
301     N   5/03/2016
```

Desired Output:

```
101    N    4/14/2016    0
501    N    4/21/2016    3
301    N    5/03/2016    2
```

I need the count of successful cases between 2 failed events to plot the G charts. 
I could really use some help finding an approach to count the successful cases.

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: How do we know the row with 301 comes after the row with 701, and not before it? They have the same date!

Comment: They are just a random number. I just wanted to clear that the col1 is not a primary key.

Comment: Do you mean it is not "unique"? (I assume it is "not null".) If it is not unique, how do you decide if the Y or the N should be considered "first" (coming before the other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the DT column (the third one) does not have duplicate values - I changed the last date to reflect that, in my test data - this can be solved by counting the 'Y' rows in an inner query (use a CASE expression inside an analytic COUNT), and then in the outer query we can filter for just the rows with 'N' and use a lagged difference (again an analytic function application).

If there can be ties in the DT column, then the OP needs to clarify the requirement - but whatever it is, it can be accommodated easily in this solution.

```
with
     test_data ( id, success, dt ) as (
       select 101, 'N', to_date('4/14/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 201, 'Y', to_date('4/15/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 301, 'Y', to_date('4/16/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 401, 'Y', to_date('4/20/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 501, 'N', to_date('4/21/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 201, 'Y', to_date('4/30/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 701, 'Y', to_date('5/03/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 301, 'N', to_date('5/04/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
     )
--  End of simulated data (for testing purposes only).
--  Solution (SQL query) begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select id, success, dt, ct - lag(ct, 1, 0) over (order by dt) as success_count
from   (
         select id, success, dt,
                count(case when success = 'Y' then 1 end) over (order by dt) as ct
         from   test_data
       )
where  success = 'N'
;

 ID SUCCESS DT         SUCCESS_COUNT
--- ------- ---------- -------------
101 N       14/04/2016             0
501 N       21/04/2016             3
301 N       04/05/2016             2
```

Comment: We do have one more column which is in the datetime format. It's sorted accordingly. But this is what I was trying to figure out. It worked for me. Thank you @mathguy. :)

Comment: @SJA - This is one of the beauties of analytic functions - the analytic clause (PARTITION BY and ORDER BY in the OVER clause) has a lot of flexibility, you can order by any expression or combination of expressions you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate groups by using the count of "N" events before that.  Then, your query is just an aggregation query:

```
select min(col1) as col1, min('N') as col2, min(date) as col3,
       sum(case when col2 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col2 = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col3) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Min(date) will create a problem. As in the end I will need only date and the count of cases.

Comment: 101          Y 4/1/2016
102          Y 4/1/2016
103          N 4/2/2016
104          Y 4/2/2016
105          N 4/3/2016                                                                            Running your query gives the following output:                                                  N 4/1/2016 2
N 4/2/2016 1
N 4/3/2016 0